# How can I go from one xml layout to another

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am a noob at developing apps and am just learning, and for that reason I am getting errors. How would you do it in the Java? This is what I did:

```
           //This is under the menu where I would click the button

`package com.shipment.emulatorfix;
`import android.app.Activity;
`import android.content.Intent;
`import android.os.Bundle;
`import android.view.View;
`import android.widget.Button;

 public class TestingEmulatorActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button strikes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStrikes);
    strikes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.package.testingemulator.STRIKES"));
        }
    }); 



}


}


   `
```

//This is under the new layout

```
 `       package com.shipment.emulatorfix;

 `import android.app.Activity;
 `import android.os.Bundle;

 `public class strikes extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.strikes);
} 

   `}
```

---

Thank you, and please tell me any changes or what you would do to go to the other layout.
THANK YOU!

Comment: Can u clear on what you want to acheive

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
 startActivity(new Intent(TestingEmulatorActivity.this, strikes.class));
```

instead of

```
 startActivity(new Intent("com.package.testingemulator.STRIKES"));
```

Comment: If answer is satisfied you can check mark it so that other users don't answer thinking your problem as unresolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

[1] call startActivity to open another layout.

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), _second.class));
```

[2]  Create another XML layout file which you want to display.

[3]  Create new class and give it the name like "_second.java"

```
    public class _second extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
}

}
```

[4]  and MOST IMPORTANTLY, register your new class activity in androidmanifest.xml file.
This line must be in

```
    <application>...</application>
```

tag. just like

```
    <application>
    <activity android:name="._second" />
    </application>
```

That's it.